# T-SQL: Row-Number only for rows with a filled field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a primary key of type integer, and two varchar columns, like this:

```
id   name    remarks 
-------------------------
1    text1   
2    text2   anyRemarks
3    text3   
4    text4   anyRemarks
5    text5
6    text6
7    text7   anyRemarks
```

Only some of the remarks are filled.

Now I wanted a computed row number but only for the rows which have filled remarks. I need all rows in the result but counter should only increased if remarks is filled. So the desired result is this:

```
id   name    remarks     counter
----------------------------------
1    text1               0
2    text2   anyRemarks  1
3    text3               0
4    text4   anyRemarks  2
5    text5               0
6    text6               0
7    text7   anyRemarks  3
```

My approach was using row_number and do a select like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, name, remarks, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS counter 
FROM 
    table
```

But that fills the counter for any row.

Do I need to work with a sub select?

Any other suggestions?

(The engine is SQL Server 2017 so all current features can be used)

Comment: Have you considering using a `CASE` expression? Also, why `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` and not `ORDER BY id`? Are you happy with the ordering of `counter` being random?

Comment: Yes, of course I can use ORDER BY (SELECT id) but that doesn't make a difference for creating the conditional row number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach to get your results:

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
    id int,
    name varchar(10),    
    remarks varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO #Table
    (id, name, remarks)
VALUES
    (1, 'text1', NULL),
    (2, 'text2', 'anyRemarks'),
    (3, 'text3', NULL),
    (4, 'text4', 'anyRemarks'),
    (5, 'text5', NULL),
    (6, 'text6', NULL),
    (7, 'text7', 'anyRemark')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    remarks,
    CASE
        WHEN remarks IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN remarks is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY id)
    END AS [Rn]
FROM #Table
ORDER BY id
```

Output:

```
id  name    remarks     Rn
1   text1   NULL        0
2   text2   anyRemarks  1
3   text3   NULL        0
4   text4   anyRemarks  2
5   text5   NULL        0
6   text6   NULL        0
7   text7   anyRemark   3
```

Answer (score 1):

By the order of the ids:

```
SELECT 
  t.id, t.name, t.remarks, 
  case 
    when t.remarks is null then 0
    else (select count(*) from table where remarks is not null and id < t.id) + 1 
  end as counter 
FROM table t
ORDER BY t.id
```

or with UNION ALL:

```
select *, 0 as counter from [table] where remarks is null
union all
select *, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY (id)) from [table] where remarks is not null
order by id
```

Comment: This definitely produces the correct result but a window function will be better for performance as it won't hit the table a second time. For small result sets it probably doesn't make much difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the window function `SUM` to get a running total, and then a `CASE` statement in the `SELECT` to check if the running total should be shown.

```
;with cte as
(
    select  *, SUM(case when remarks is null then 0 else 1 end) OVER (ORDER BY id)numRemarks 
    from #Table
)

select id, name, remarks, case when remarks is null then 0 else numRemarks end as counter 
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option would be to use `count` with `over` clause:

```
SELECT  Id, 
        Name, 
        Remarks, 
        CASE WHEN Remarks IS NULL THEN 0 
        ELSE COUNT(Remarks) OVER(ORDER BY Id) END As Rn
FROM #Table
```